# How can I change order values in a table when inserting a new row with a higher order value?

Tags: php, mysql

Using php and mysqli, I have a categories table that group products and control the order they are displayed in my catalog. The field "ord" is an int with the value that controls the order these product categories are displayed. When inserting a new category, I would like to reorder the remaining categories from the new category down and update the table then insert the new category without duplicating the "ord" value.

There are 11 categories. I want to insert my new category with it's "ord" value as 5. Clearly I need to add 1 to each "ord" values 6 - 11 to reorder my catalog. Not sure how to do this. I'm not good with arrays but I would think some sort of foreach array[$key][] + 1  with an UPDATE to the table would work. I'm not clear on how to create the array.

Don't really have any working ideas on this...

```
Category ord=1: Site Licensing
Category ord=2: PICC Insertion Training
Category ord=3: Ultrasound Training
```

New Category: ord 2: Membership Subscriptions

```
Category ord=1: Site Licensing
Category ord=2: Membership Subscriptions
Category ord=3: PICC Insertion Training
Category ord=4: Ultrasound Training
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update the table before doing the `INSERT`. By updating the existing data first, you leave a space for your new entry.

```
$order = $_POST['order'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `categories` set order = order + 1 where order >= ?"));

$stmt->bind_param("i", $order);

$stmt->execute();

/** Now perform INSERT statement */
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! I've been tinkering while waiting for a response and actually answered my own quesiton.  Changing the select statement to include only those records that are equal to or greater than the new order value get's the records I want. Then do the update and then the insert. I made this harder by over thinking it.